# SUM a range of cells that contain letters

Tags: excel, sum

I have a column that equates a weighted average for each question. If a user selects N/A for the answer, my formula will equate this as "N/A", I would like a formula that sums this as N/A.  I am currently using a SUM formula and it is displaying 0%.  I need it to calculate this as "N/A" and display this in the cell.   For example, in a cell I have the SUM formula SUM(L140:L150).  Among this range of cells, there are entries that will be N/A.  If all the cells in L140:L150 are N/A, I would like the cell to show N/A and not 0%.

Answer (score 1):

You could just calculate if the sum of cells containing `N/A` is the same as the sum of everything and if true, display `N/A`

```
=IF(COUNTIF(L140:L150;"N/A")=COUNTA(L140:L150);"N/A";SUM(L140:L150))
```

### Demo

*The last line is the one with the `SUM`*

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @user9425493 you're welcome, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :)